# Running gnome-terminal with alt-f2 doesn't set the SSH_AUTH_SOCKET env variable

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, ssh, gnome-terminal

I've set gnome-keyring to unlock my ssh key on login, and usually first thing I do after logging in is to run a gnome terminal via the `Alt-F2` shortcut,

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=90x40 -e byobu
```

This worked fine until a couple of days ago, I could login to my usual servers without being prompted for the ssh-key passphrase. Today it stopped working, and after some poking around it seems that the `SSH_AUTH_SOCKET` variable is not being set when running gnome-terminal via the `Alt-F2` shortcut. Everything is fine clicking on the terminal icon in the dash, typing `Terminal` after tapping the `Super` key or using the `Ctrl-Alt-T` shotrcut.